# Adobe Illustrator text selection different from other document

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, textselection

I am doing a copy-paste job from Word to Illustrator, whenever I double click on the word in the docx the whole word is selected like this

[image]

but when I try to double click in illustrator it leaves the first point out and selects the last "/" or selects the whole word but not just the middle part.

[image]

[image]

what could be the reason for that, and is there an easier way to do that

Comment: Alas, MS Word and Adobe Illustrator have the different visions of how to select 'word' with double click, indeed. Perhaps there can be a workaround in Illustratror. There could be a script that will select (and/or copy) a word in Word-like style or/and some keyboard shortcuts via apps like AutoHotkey (in Windows). The implementation depends on your workflow.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes, I tried the solution didn't worked so I did some other thing to solve the issue, I will delete this question

Answer (score 0):

For simplest cases you can modify the selected range this way:

```
var sel = app.selection; // get the selection
sel.start += 1;          // remove first letter from the range
sel.end -= 1;            // remove last letter from the range
sel.select();            // select the new range
app.copy();              // copy selected text in clipboard
```

You can put the script into an action and assign some keyboard shortcut for the action.